# ULS Log event email notification

Tags: events, logging, administration

Is it possible to configure Sharepoint such that it emails me whenever an event with exception severity occurs? If yes then how do I configure it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good question. I don't believe there is an out of the box solution, but you can install [SPTraceView](http://sptraceview.codeplex.com/) and choose to re-route certain events to the event log. You can then consolidate your windows events log using any of the many tools available and send out email alerts.

I believe someone will need to be logged in to the server in order to run SPTraceView, but it maybe possible to run this tool remotely as well.

Answer (score 4):

The 'enterprise' way to do this would be to use a proper monitoring tool such as Microsoft Operations Manager. The process I have in mind would involve:

- Configure SharePoint diagnostic logging such that the 'least severe' event to write to the Windows event log is [your desired severity threshold]
- Configure MOM to e-mail alert you whenever something is logged to the Windows event log with source 'x' (SharePoint) and severity 'y'

This way you also have a more permanent record of your events, as the Windows event log will likely be kept for longer than the SharePoint ULS logs. Pay attention to that though..

Comment: Thats a clean approach the only problem though can be that I'll loose the log entries that are not critical but could be helpful in diagnosing a critical problem.

Comment: Hmm, not necessarily. It would come down to what retention you specify for both (SP logs + Windows event logs). Also I'm pretty sure MOM helps by giving an aggregated view of entries across different sources for a particular point in time.